# What happen if I gain the control of aura that enchants an opponent's creature? Would the aura stay attached?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Imagine I'm playing vs Boggles Auras. Her Boggle has a [Rancor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRancor%5d) and a [Daybreak Coronet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDaybreak%20Coronet%5d).

I cast [Archmage's Charm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArchmage%27s%5d%2b%5bCharm%5d) on the Rancor.

Does the Rancor stay enchanting the Boggle?

Comment: While one can conclude from context that you're choosing the "Gain control of target nonland permanent with converted mana cost 1 or less." mode, I think that should be made explicit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, *most of the times* it doesn't matter who controls the aura and who controls the creature. There are a handful of exceptions, e.g. [Cartouche of Knowledge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCartouche%20of%20Knowledge%5d) which can only enchant a creature you control; if you'd steal one of them it would stop enchanting a legal target and be put into its owner's graveyard.

> 303.4c If an Aura is enchanting an illegal object or player as defined by its enchant ability and other applicable effects, the object it was attached to no longer exists, or the player it was attached to has left the game, the Aura is put into its owner’s graveyard. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.)

Note that stealing an Aura isn't really useful if the Aura grants a bonus/ability to the creature (which is most of the time); it *might* be useful if the Aura has an ability itself.

> 303.4e An Aura’s controller is separate from the enchanted object’s controller or the enchanted player; the two need not be the same. If an Aura enchants an object, changing control of the object doesn’t change control of the Aura, and vice versa. Only the Aura’s controller can activate its abilities. However, if the Aura grants an ability to the enchanted object (with “gains” or “has”), the enchanted object’s controller is the only one who can activate that ability.

Comment: Also, any references to "you" refer to the owner of the aura. So gaining control of an aura that says "You control enchanted creature" would mean that you control the enchanted creature.

Comment: @Acccumulation Unless I'm mistaken, it refers to the controller of the aura, who might not currently be the owner.

Comment: @eyeballfrog You're right, if they're different, it's the controller.